# How to select one item in LINQ when the other is null

Tags: c#, linq

This maybe a simple question but i have the following code:

```
string lol = "540";
        var values = from pv in dataRecords.Values
                     where pv.ID.Contains(lol)
                     || pv.TotalLength.Contains(lol)
                     from tv in pv.MyProperty
                     where tv.name.Contains(lol)
                     || tv.length.Contains(lol)
                     || tv.startByte.Contains(lol)

                     select
```

But i need to select pv when tv is null and vice versa i know this is very simple but its the end of the day and i cant think right now. Also would like to increase my LINQ knowledge so any interesting guides would be great.

**EDIT** To give a bit more information tv breaks down a subclass of datarecords so i can search those fields the string lol. I am just looking to select one that returns a result basically not null.

Comment: `pv when tv is null and vice versa` you select `tv` from `pv.MyProperty`. How can you select `tv` when `pv` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pv` and `tv` happen to be the same type you can do this:

```
var values = from pv in dataRecords.Values
             where pv.ID.Contains(lol)
             || pv.TotalLength.Contains(lol)
             from tv in pv.MyProperty
             where tv.name.Contains(lol)
             || tv.length.Contains(lol)
             || tv.startByte.Contains(lol)
             select tv ?? pv;
```

However, you can only have one return type, so if `pv` and `tv` are different types you'll have issues. You can do this:

```
var values = from pv in dataRecords.Values
             where pv.ID.Contains(lol)
             || pv.TotalLength.Contains(lol)
             from tv in pv.MyProperty
             where tv.name.Contains(lol)
             || tv.length.Contains(lol)
             || tv.startByte.Contains(lol)
             select new { pv, tv };
foreach(var v in values)
{
    if (v.tv == null) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caution: this is a **hack** ( o_O  ). But it will result in `tv` being returned if `pv` is null:

```
var values = from pv in dataRecords.Values
         where pv.ID.Contains(lol)
         || pv.TotalLength.Contains(lol)
         from tv in pv.MyProperty
         where tv.name.Contains(lol)
         || tv.length.Contains(lol)
         || tv.startByte.Contains(lol)
         select ((object)tv ?? (object)pv);
```

Remember to unbox before you consume the `values` IEnumerable.